# How to pass MSBuild parameters in launchSettings.json?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, msbuild

I have project that I built using VS Code. The project should be built differently (using `#IF` directives) depending on MSBuild Parameter passed to it (let's say that parameter name is `MyParameter`). The amount of possible values or that parameter is finite (let's say 5). I solved that in VS Code by having 5 different configurations (in `launch.json`) and a build task for each configuration (in `tasks.json`) which would pass the appropriate value to MSBuild parameter. I had one `.csproj` file with this line:

`<DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);$(MyParameter)</DefineConstants>`

I tried using VS 2022 and the only way to do something similar to this is having multiple solution configurations. I see that VS uses `launchSettings.json` for its launch profiles. Is there any way to pass MSBuild parameters in a `launchSettings.json` profile?

Comment: Other ways: start a shell, set MyParameter as environment variable, then start VS from that shell and it will use the environment variable. Or use directory.build.props. Or don't do any of that, instead use a shell script and run the 5 different builds from there passing /p:MyParameter=foo. The latter makes most sense to me personally, but I might be missing why it's important for you to ba able to have the 5 different configurations easily toggable in VS.

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2022 17.3 and newer the *launchsettings.json* behavior has been aligned with VS Code slightly. You can use something like `{ProjectDir}` now in parameters. That is especially important for *DockerfileRunArguments*:

```
"DockerfileRunArguments": "-v \"{ProjectDir}\\project\\localkeys:/azure-functions-host/Secrets\""
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-launch-settings?view=vs-2022

> Note that elder sources refer to `$(ProjectDir)` syntax, which is not correct. It's in curly braces actually.